# R: Calculate difference between values in rows with group reference

Tags: r

This is my df:

```
group value
1     10
1     20
1     25
2     5
2     10
2     15
```

I now want to compute differences between each value of a group and a reference value, which is the first row of a group. More precisely:

```
group value diff
1     10    NA # because this is the reference for group 1
1     20    10 # value[2] - value[1]
1     25    15 # value[3] - value[1]
2     5     NA # because this is the reference for group 2
2     10    5  # value[5] - value[4]
2     15    10 # value[6] - value[4]
```

I found good answers for difference scores of the previous line (e.g., lag-function in dpylr, shift-function in data.table). However, I am looking for a fixed reference point and I couldn't make it work.

Comment: why is `value[3] - value[1] = 5` and not `15`?

Comment: Does `value[1]` refers to the value in the first row? if so why the third row for group `1` ended up with `5`? it appears it should be `15` based on this explanation. This is also the case with group `2`.

Comment: @YuriySaraykin thanks for noticing, that was a mistake!

Comment: @diggi2395, see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below

```
transform(
    df,
    Diff = ave(value, group, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
)
```

which gives

```
  group value Diff
1     1    10   NA
2     1    20   10
3     1    25    5
4     2     5   NA
5     2    10    5
6     2    15    5
```

Comment: I can't upvote yet but this function did exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, Thomas!

Comment: Can I ask you one additional question? How to change the ave function when I want to use the residuals of regressing (instead of only subtracting) the values? So instead of "value 2 - value 1", I might be interested in "lm(value2 ~ value1)$residuals".

Comment: @diggi2395 Maybe you can try `c(NA,lm(tail(x, -1) ~ head(x, -1))$residuals)` to replace the function in `ave`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can also use this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(diff = value - value[1], 
         diff = replace(diff, row_number() == 1, NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group value  diff
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1    10    NA
2     1    20    10
3     1    25    15
4     2     5    NA
5     2    10     5
6     2    15    10
```

Comment: Again, I can't upvote yet. Great answer, thanks for your dplyr solution!

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <-
  structure(list(
    group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
    value = c(10L,
              20L, 25L, 5L, 10L, 15L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,
                -6L))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(DIFF = ifelse(row_number() == 1, NA, value - first(value))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   group value  DIFF
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1    10    NA
#> 2     1    20    10
#> 3     1    25    15
#> 4     2     5    NA
#> 5     2    10     5
#> 6     2    15    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry that I can't upvote your answer yet.